# How to get all Users to populate a People Picker Control using PnP JS Core (SharePoint Online/ SharePoint 2016)

Tags: sharepoint-framework, pnp-js-core

Can I use PnP JS library to get all Users to populate a People Picker Control ?

Regards,

Arioule

Answer (score 0):

To populate a custom drop-down ( which you are calling as people picker field), first get the users from the site using following snippet:

```
 $pnp.sp.web.siteUsers.get().then(function(data) {
    var users = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        users += data[i].Id + " - " + data[i].Title + "<br/>";
    }
    document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = users;
});
```

Now populate the drop-down with the above users, refer [this](http://www.ktskumar.com/2016/07/pnp-js-core-gets-users-site-collection/)

Comment: this will get all site users, is there any method to get all tenant level user. then i have to add that users to site.